# Django ImageField обновление изображения

Tags: python, django

Есть модель, пользователя, в которой есть поле avatar, которое по умолчанию заполняется картинкой:

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
"""
Аккаунт пользователя
"""
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Account'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Accounts'

.... Другие поля модели ....

avatar = models.ImageField(
    blank=True,
    verbose_name='Avatar',
    upload_to=f'account/avatar/',
    default='../static/img/account/noimage.png'
)
```

Проблема состоит в том, что, когда я хочу обновить автар пользователя, ничего не происходит (если делать в админке всё ок)

HTML-шаблон

```
<div id="edit_account_profile">
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in user_edit_form %}
    <p>{{ field }}<p>
    {% endfor%}
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Save">
</form>
```

Форма:

```
class AccountEditForm(UserChangeForm):
"""
Форма для редактирования аккаунта пользователя
"""
first_name = forms.CharField(required=False,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                 'class': 'fadeIn second',
                                 'placeholder': 'First name',
                             }))
last_name = forms.CharField(required=False,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                'class': 'fadeIn second',
                                'placeholder': 'Last name',
                            }))
about_me = forms.CharField(required=False,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                               'class': 'fadeIn second',
                               'placeholder': 'About me',
                           }))
location = forms.CharField(required=False,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                               'class': 'fadeIn second',
                               'placeholder': 'Location',
                           }))
avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False,
                          widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
                              'class': 'fadeIn second',
                              'placeholder': 'Avatar',
                          }))

class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'about_me', 'location', 'avatar')
```

Вьюшка:

```
def get_user_edit(request):
"""
Изменение данных пользователя
"""
if request.POST:
    user_edit_form = AccountEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if user_edit_form.is_valid():
        user_edit_form.save()
        return redirect('account:profile')

else:
    user_edit_form = AccountEditForm(instance=request.user)
return render(request, 'account/settings.html', {'user_edit_form': user_edit_form})
```

Comment: Забыли передать request.FILES в форму

Comment: @andreymal Вставляю user_edit_form = AccountEditForm(request.POST, request.FILES,  instance=request.user), но также не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вы в теге form на html странице не отметили

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, решило проблему